# Container View Page Controller is Being Clipped instead of Resized

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am about fifteen seconds away from flipping over my desk and rage quitting, because I just *cannot* figure this out.

I have a Page View Controller as the embed of a Container View Controller. Sounds easy, right?

Problem is, the Page View Controller is getting *clipped*. I need it to resize. So they would be cute little pages with their full VC content.

I've tried every option on the Storyboard Display... things.

Here's a couple of pics to describe the problem:

[image: The primary storyboard set up. Notice how the name of the Page View Controller is clipped.]
[image: One of the view controllers I am trying to present as a page in the Page View Controller. Ignore its ugliness.]
[image: How to aforementioned Page ends up when running the Simulator.]

Now I would share the code with you, but all it is the loading of the (single) page. The page does exist in a different storyboard, but even when I changed the view for View Controllers in the Main storyboard, they were still being cut off.

```
override viewDidLoad() {
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TEMPLATES", bundle: Bundle.main)

let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "template1")

self.setViewControllers([vc!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

 self.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] //Some code I found on Stack Overflow that did nothing

 super.viewDidLoad()
```

}

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add it from the storyboard - it will just work.

if you add the child view controller from code - you also need to set the frame like so:

```
carsTableVC.view.frame = self.container.bounds
```

here is a full code example (carsTableVC is in a container):

```
let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Cars", bundle: nil)

self.carsTableVC =
    sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
        "CarsTableViewController") as? CarsTableViewController

carsTableVC.view.frame = self.container.bounds
carsTableVC.willMove(toParent: self)
addChild(carsTableVC)
carsTableVC.didMove(toParent: self)
container.addSubview(carsTableVC.view)
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much, can’t believe I missed something so simple